# Tough substitution inequality

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that if $x, y, z >0$ and $xyz=x+y+z+2$, then

$$
\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} \leq \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{xyz}.
$$

By the way, the first equation implies the existence of positive $a, b, c$ such that $x=\frac{b+c}{a}, y=\frac{c+a}{b}, z=\frac{a+b}{c}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea works.

Let $x=\frac{b+c}{a}$ and $y=\frac{a+c}{b},$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

Thus, $z=\frac{a+b}{c}$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a}}\leq\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}{abc}}$$  or
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab}{(a+c)(b+c)}}\leq\frac{3}{2},$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{ab}{(a+c)(b+c)}}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{a+c}+\frac{b}{b+c}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a}{a+c}+\frac{c}{c+a}\right)=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: What is the meaning of cyc?

Comment: @Dunkel It's a cyclic sum. For example, for three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have: $\sum\limits_{cyc}a=a+b+c$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a}}=\sqrt{\frac{b+c}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{c}}.$

Comment: thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @Dunkel You are welcome!